# Load Xib into UIView without add it as a subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, xib

How can I load a nib into a `UIView` without having to add it as a `subview`? In objc you were able to do in the init method self = `[NSBundle MainBundle].loadNibNamed…` but swift says `“Cannot assign to ‘self’ in a method”`

[image]

In Object you were able to do this. [Reusable Views](http://nathanhjones.com/2011/02/20/creating-reusable-uiviews-with-a-drop-shadow-tutorial/)
But seems swift doesnt like it.
The only approax i found is to loading the Xib into a UIView and add it as a subView of the current view

```
@IBDesignable class CustomViewFromXib: UIView 
{
    var nibName: String = "CustomViewFromXib"
    override init(frame: CGRect) 
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) 
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() 
    {
        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Comment: My viewController? I dont have here a view controller, plus i probably don't want it. Read the tutorial i posted.

Comment: How is this view going to get on screen? -> now i have a Xib where it holds a subivew and i set the class in the Class Inspector to "CustomViewFromXib". This is already ALREADY working. The annoying part is i have to add the Xib view as a subview of the view  ( self.view.addSubview(view) ). Previously in objc you didnt have to add it as a subview, as you can see here: http://nathanhjones.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/Screen-shot-2011-02-20-at-8.43.55-PM.png (Is a screenshot of the link i posted).

Comment: Probably my missing is that i'm adding the view inside a view in a Xib file, not by code.

Answer (score -1):

[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myNib" owner:self options:nil];

is another way of doing it and setting the owner of it.

It' a bit slippy and would probably break the KVO/KVC side of things

Comment: var badArray: NSArray?;
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("theView",owner:theOwner, topLevelObjects:&badArray)

Comment: What is This for? Its not related to my question

Comment: What does the code even accomplish? It doesn't address OP's question at all